# Standalone.xml file of jboss equivalent in websphere

Tags: jboss, migration, websphere, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to migrate a web app from Websphere to JBoss.

I believe the first step is to port the configurations of the server. The main configuration file in Jboss is standalone.xml (or domain.xml for running multiple instances of a server).

Could you tell me what the equivalent of standalone.xml is in websphere ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent.  WebSphere is administered via the administration console.  If you run WebSphere Express you can connect directly to the app. server's administration port.  If you run Network Deployment, you connect to the deployment manager console (DMGR).

The console has all the configuration.  They are stored in many XML files, that can be a pain to use directly.  Much easier with the console.

The default console port is 9060 (http) or 9043 (https).

URL:

```
http://yourserver:9060/ibm/console
https://yourserver:9043/ibm/console
```

See this technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21155098
for a bit more information.

You can look at this migration guide for JBoss AS 7.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebSphere+to+AS+7?_sscc=t